# Regular Expression, using non-greedy to catch optional string

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I am parsing the content of a PDF with PDFMiner and sometimes, there is a line that is present and other time not.  I am trying to express the optional line without any success.  Here is a piece of code that shows the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=UTF8

import re

# Simulate reading text of a PDF file with PDFMiner.
pdfContent = """

Blah blah.

Date:  2022-01-31

Optional line here which sometimes does not show

Amount:  123.45

2: Blah blah.

"""

RE = re.compile(
    r".*?"
    "Date:\s+(\S+).*?"
    "(Optional line here which sometimes does not show){0,1}.*?"
    "Amount:\s+(?P<amount>\S+)\n.*?"
    , re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

matches = RE.match(pdfContent)

date     = matches.group(1)
optional = matches.group(2)
amount   = matches.group("amount")

print(f"date     = {date}")
print(f"optional = {optional}")
print(f"amount   = {amount}")
```

The output is:

```
date     = 2022-01-31
optional = None
amount   = 123.45
```

Why is optional *None*?  Notice that if I replace the `{0,1}` with `{1}`, it works!  But, then the line is not optional anymore.  I do use the non-greedy `.*?` everywhere...

This is probably a duplicate, but I searched and searched and did not find my answer, thus this question.

Comment: `{0,1}` is synonym of `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.search` (instead of `re.match`) with

```
Date:\s+(\S+)(?:.*?(Optional line here which sometimes does not show))?.*?Amount:\s+(?P<amount>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzGj8T/1).

In this pattern, `.*?(Optional line here which sometimes does not show)?` (`{0,1}` = `?`) is wrapped with an optional non-capturing group, `(?:...)?`, that *must* be tried at least once since `?` is a greedy quantifier.

In your code, you can use it as

```py
RE = re.compile(
    r"Date:\s+(\S+)(?:.*?"
    r"(Optional line here which sometimes does not show))?.*?"
    r"Amount:\s+(?P<amount>\S+)",
    re.DOTALL)

matches = RE.search(pdfContent)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NxCXxW):

```py
import re
 
pdfContent = "\n\nBlah blah.\n\nDate:  2022-01-31\n\nOptional line here which sometimes does not show\n\nAmount:  123.45\n\n2: Blah blah.\n"
 
RE = re.compile(
    r"Date:\s+(\S+)(?:.*?"
    r"(Optional line here which sometimes does not show))?.*?"
    r"Amount:\s+(?P<amount>\S+)",
    re.DOTALL)
 
matches = RE.search(pdfContent)
date     = matches.group(1)
optional = matches.group(2)
amount   = matches.group("amount")
 
print(f"date     = {date}")
print(f"optional = {optional}")
print(f"amount   = {amount}")
```

Output:

```
date     = 2022-01-31
optional = Optional line here which sometimes does not show
amount   = 123.45
```